# How to use lodash and local types in monaco-editor

Tags: typescript, sveltekit, monaco-editor

I'm using `monaco-editor` in a SvelteKit component

```html
<!-- Editor.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
  import loader from '@monaco-editor/loader';
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';
  import type * as Monaco from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api';
  export let code: string;

  let editor: Monaco.editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor;
  let monaco: typeof Monaco;
  let editorContainer: HTMLElement;

  onMount(async () => {
    const monacoEditor = await import('monaco-editor');
    loader.config({ monaco: monacoEditor.default });
    monaco = await loader.init();
    const editor = monaco.editor.create(editorContainer, {
      value: [
        code,
      ].join('\n'),
      language: 'typescript',
    });
  });
</script>
```

I want to write functions such as these inside the editor

```
function add(num1: SomeNumber, num2: SomeNumber): SomeNumber {
  _.sample(); // or anything from lodash
  // ...
}
```

Where I have a file `$lib/src/ts/somenumber.ts` that contains the `SomeNumber` class, and also `$lib/src/ts/index.ts` which contains things like

```
export type { SomeNumber } from "./somenumber";
```